# Rotate an SVG when a section enters the viewport using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Looking to reproduce something like the samples on this page:
https://university.signnow.com/samples/

I need an arrow that sits at the bottom of the page until it hits a specific area (in this case, blue text area), then the arrow rotates -90deg. If at any point the user clicks the arrow, you scroll to the blue text area and the arrow is rotated. I would use jQuery to change the class of the arrow once you hit 2000px (or whatever it would be) down the page, but this is a dynamic page and we can't hard code something like that.

Any help is very much appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/5s25vzj0/

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="#jump">
    <svg id="flag" class="flag" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="73">
      <path fill="#04BE5B" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0h31v61.7L16 73c.4 0-16-11.3-16-11.3V0z"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
  <div id="top">
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="jump" class="blue">
    <svg id="horz-flag" class="hidden" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31" height="73">
      <path fill="#04BE5B" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0h31v61.7L16 73c.4 0-16-11.3-16-11.3V0z"/>
    </svg>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Couldn't you use some type of logic to say if we've scrolled 2000px or 75% of the window height, do your action? I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly

Comment: @jas7457 unfortunately not. This needs to work on mobile devices, and the text may change (so the height it sits at will change too).

Comment: That's where the 75% of the document height would come into play.

Comment: @jas7457 unfortunately, the arrow will need to appear exactly where the blue bottom text begins - can't really estimate. Looking for a way to rotate the arrow once the blue text area is visible in the view port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I misread your original specifications. You can have a scroll listener to listen to when it scrolls a certain element into view, in this instance, `.blue`

```
var topofDiv = $( '.blue' ).offset().top; //gets offset of blue text
var $window  = $( window );
var $flag    = $( '.flag' );

$window.scroll( function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() + $window.height() > topofDiv ) {
        $flag.addClass( 'red' );
    }
    else {
        $flag.removeClass( 'red' );
    }
} );
```

Check out the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6wdgdd2/